# Percentage in array of hashes?

Tags: arrays, ruby, percentage, ruby-hash

I have `hash` and an array of hashes `array`:

```rb
hash = {"BEGIN"=>5, "END"=>10}


array = [
    {:name=>"aaa", :phase=>"END", :quantity=>6},
    {:name=>"bbb", :phase=>"END", :quantity=>4},
    {:name=>"ccc", :phase=>"BEGIN", :quantity=>5}
  ]
```

How can I calculate the percentage on the array of hashes taking the value from hash and get this result?

```rb
[
  {:name=>"aaa", :phase=>"END", :quantity=>60%},
  {:name=>"bbb", :phase=>"END", :quantity=>40%},
  {:name=>"ccc", :phase=>"BEGIN", :quantity=>100%}
]
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The result you want is not legal Ruby, therefore it is impossible to get this result.

Comment: @Jörg is pointing out that, for example, `60%` is not a Ruby object. You could write `60` or `"60%"`.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right and I knew it, it was an oversight! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get percents as integers

```
hash = { "BEGIN" => 5, "END" => 10 }

array = [
  { name: "aaa", phase: "END", quantity: 6 },
  { name: "bbb", phase: "END", quantity: 4 },
  { name: "ccc", phase: "BEGIN", quantity: 5 }
]

array.map! { |el| el.merge(quantity: el[:quantity] * 100 / hash[el[:phase]]) }

p array
# will print
# [{:name=>"aaa", :phase=>"END", :quantity=>60}, {:name=>"bbb", :phase=>"END", :quantity=>40}, {:name=>"ccc", :phase=>"BEGIN", :quantity=>100}]
```

or you using each

```
array.each { |el| el[:quantity] = el[:quantity] * 100 / hash[el[:phase]] }
```